# XSD.exe and creating references to parent elements.

Tags: c#, xsd, xsd.exe

Suppose I have the following schema

```
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="Company" type="Employer" />
<xs:complexType name="Employer">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Address" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="Phone" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="Employees" type="Person" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="Person">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="SSN" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>`
```

I used XSD to generate the Person and Employer classes. The Employer class contains a list of Persons as expected but I also want each person to contain a pointer to it's parent element Employer. How can I make XSD do that?

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be to write your own extensions to the generated classes that include a Parent member. It's not a great solution since the Parent property will not be filled with data automatically by the XML serializer, so it will have to be done manually.